# Remove 1px gap when using display:flex with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

In some browsers, such as Safari 9, the following bootstrap grid is leaving a 1px gap on either side of the `row` element. Why is that?

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.a {background-color:#eee}
.b {background-color:#ddd}
.row {background-color:red}

.vertical-align {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 a">Hello</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 b">World</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div class="col-xs-6 a">Hello</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 b">World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like it's the "clearfix". You`ll have to remove the row class. You don't need floats if you're using flex anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The gap is caused by the clearfix gap - `content: " "` - which is on pseudo elements of the bootstrap `.row` class.

To prevent the gap:

1. Remove the "row" class as well as the parents "container" class

**or**

2. Remove the clearfix pseudo element with:

```
div.vertical-align:before, div.vertical-align:after { display: none }
```

**Note:** Placing "div" before the class selector - `.vertical-align` - prevents the need for `!important`

### The two examples

#### Without removing the row class

```css
.a {
  background-color: #eee
}
.b {
  background-color: #ddd
}
.row {
  background-color: red
}
.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
div.vertical-align:before,
div.vertical-align:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 a">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 b">World</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row vertical-align">
    <div class="col-xs-6 a">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 b">World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### With the removal of the row class.

The class - `.container` - also needs to be removed.

```css
.a {
  background-color: #eee
}
.b {
  background-color: #ddd
}
.row {
  background-color: red
}
.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
div.vertical-align:before,
div.vertical-align:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 a">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 b">World</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <div class="vertical-align">
    <div class="col-xs-6 a">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 b">World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But for those who end up with this problem, I had to change the classes in order to fix it: `div.row:before, div.row:after { display: none }`.

Comment: @PauloTorrens - Just be mindful that this will eliminate the Bootstrap clearfix for all your rows, so make sure you really don't need it :) - you could also apply a custom class to the rows where you want to remove the clearfix.

Comment: Just found that out. So I put a custom class that would eliminate :before and :after, both for the row and for the clearfixes (which I used for a liquid boxes layout). =P