# Equal height Flexbox columns in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a simple, 2-column layout and I'd like to use Flexbox to get equal heights:

HTML

```
<div class="row flex">
    <!-- menu -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <aside>
            Menu goes here
        </aside>    
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac elementum justo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus nec elementum erat. Suspendisse consequat ut metus ut cursus. Aenean et lectus id libero venenatis varius. Vivamus luctus ligula sit amet faucibus vulputate. Vestibulum tincidunt fringilla mauris, a vulputate magna egestas nec. Vivamus a odio ut nibh viverra fermentum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { color: red; }
.flex { display: flex; }
aside { background: #000; height: 100%; }
```

This is working in Firefox but not in Chrome: [here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1peydwu/2/)

I tried something (including vendor prefixes) but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create two equal columns using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

- The parent container gets `display: flex`
- Each column is created by a div and they  get `flex: 1` to grow / shrink

To stretch the child of the first column:

- The first column is also given `display: flex` so that its children can have flex properties and grow
- The aside child is given `flex: 1` and will grow / shrink

[This is the easiest guide to Flexbox you could ask for.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Flexbox Compatibility:** [IE11+ and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

### Example

---

**With Bootstrap**: [Here is the fiddle from your comment with my changes added.](http://jsfiddle.net/9wjvk3hp/) The 1px gap on the left has been removed with `div.flex.row:before, div.flex.row:after { display: none }`

Relevant answer: [Remove 1px gap when using display:flex in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26364131/2930477)

---

I have stripped all unnecessary classes for this example. Currently, both column heights are determined by the tallest column. You could also have the columns fill in the entire height of the page with `height: 100vh` on the flex container — [read more about viewport units here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

**Viewport Units Compatibility:** [Viewport Units are *almost* well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

To give a column a larger width, give it a larger flex value. I have changed the second column in this example to `flex: 3` and it will be wider.

```css
body {
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  /*Should the columns span the entire height of the page? Use:
  height: 100vh;*/
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
}
.column:first-child {
  display: flex;
}
.column:last-of-type {
  background: #000;
  flex: 3;
}
aside {
  flex: 1;
  background: #F90;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="column">
    <aside>
      Menu goes here
    </aside>
  </div>
  <!-- content -->
  <div class="column">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac elementum justo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus nec elementum erat. Suspendisse consequat ut metus ut cursus.
      Aenean et lectus id libero venenatis varius. Vivamus luctus ligula sit amet faucibus vulputate. Vestibulum tincidunt fringilla mauris, a vulputate magna egestas nec. Vivamus a odio ut nibh viverra fermentum.</p>
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque nec libero leo. Duis porta ut neque vulputate blandit. In vel quam eu eros finibus feugiat ut in nulla. Morbi congue, tellus commodo euismod pulvinar, lacus dui fringilla lectus, in tempus mi nulla semper ex. Integer feugiat,
      lectus a facilisis rutrum, ex magna tincidunt ligula, in suscipit turpis lorem quis neque. Suspendisse dictum, nulla at aliquet cursus, magna tellus mattis purus, nec volutpat mauris nunc non neque. Mauris pretium mauris sed eros interdum lobortis.
      Aenean id vestibulum nisl. Praesent sit amet tempor nulla, consequat viverra ante. Maecenas eu pretium lacus, a consectetur sem. Proin viverra eget turpis eu condimentum. Donec et egestas enim. Maecenas fermentum auctor ligula, nec fringilla mi.
      Quisque hendrerit purus eget urna semper sodales.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks misterManSam, this is a solution but I'd like not to touch background color of first column (my "col-xs-4") and deal directly with "aside" background color (and 100% height)... is this possible?

Comment: @Ivan - No worries, I have updated my answer. The background is now applied to the `<aside>` and stretched to fill the width of the column. The first column will match the second columns height and the aside grows inside it.

Comment: Your example is working great, but still there are problems: the columns are equal width (they should be different) and on Chrome there's a small 1px gap on the left of first column: http://jsfiddle.net/e5pswtd8/1/
Anyway I accept it, even if I switched to jQuery for maintaining my mental health :-D

Comment: @Ivan - If you do want to stick with the flexbox layout, you can just give a higher flex value to the second column. I have changed my example and given the second column `flex: 3;` It will be given a larger slice of the width calculation. **The gap** is caused by the bootstrap, most likely the clearfix. You'll note there is no gap in my example.

Comment: @Ivan - [Here is your flexbox layout with that 1px left clearfix gap removed for flex divs.](http://jsfiddle.net/9wjvk3hp/) I have included the `flex: 3` to ensure the second column is wider.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution with a little bit of Modernizr and jQuery (with [Equalize plugin](https://github.com/tsvensen/equalize.js))

http://jsfiddle.net/0Leymgbe/1/

And this is what makes it work:

```
if ($().equalize) { // check if plugin is loaded
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        (Modernizr.mq("(min-width: 768px)")) // if it's tablet or desktop...
        ? $('.row').equalize({reset: true}) // then equalize the columns
        : $('.row > div').css({'height': 'auto'}); //else reset to original height
    }).resize(); // trigger the resize on page load, too
}
```

On window resize (and on load) Modernizr checks if viewport is larger than 768px (tablets and desktops): if true, then jQuery equalizes the columns; if false (smartphones), original heights are restored

No way (for me) to make it simply work with CSS3 flexbox

Comment: I believe that changes I made in my answer have reasonably addressed the problems you were having :) If the browser support of Flexbox is not an issue for you, `display: flex` is very lightweight when compared with jQuery plugins!

Comment: Yes, it was far better, thanks! Though I still have some issues with columns' widths when resizing browser: at all resolutions the columns' ratio should be 1:2 (col-xs-4 vs col-xs-8), but it's instead variable... i.e., at 768px, it's something like 1:4

Comment: I fixed the wrong ratio using `flex: 2;` instead of `flex: 3;` : http://jsfiddle.net/9wjvk3hp/2/