# Match element's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I've got a few `<div>` elements next to each other and I'd like to match their height to the highest one. Currently I do it like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $( ".services-area").each (function (index ) {
        if (maxHeight < $( this ).height()) {
            maxHeight = $( this ).height();
        }
    });

    $( ".services-area").each (function (index ) {
        $( this ).height(maxHeight);
    });
})
```

Are there better ways to achieve this result?

Comment: You can use CSS [flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090585/equal-height-flexbox-columns-in-chrome), if you don't mind incompatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Why don't use a table... In these cases it may be helpful

Comment: Did you solve this? I see various answers came through but no accept yet. Was my suggestion able to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I do this:

```
$.fn.sameHeight = function(){
    var max = 0;
    this.each(function(){
        max = Math.max($(this).height(),max);
    });
    return this.height(max);
};
```

Then I can just call it when ever I want

```
$('.column').sameHeight();
```

See Live example here
http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/t6xsjef7/

Comment: Why aren't we using `Math.max(a,b)` instead of a comparison?

Comment: No, @pabgaran. This iterates over each column and changes the variable `max` if the value of the current columns height is greater than it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CSS flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch; // Matches height of items
  justify-content: space-between; // Arranges horizontally
}
```

Quick pen: http://codepen.io/alexcoady/pen/KpgqGB

Works in all modern browsers, with partial support for IE10, but fails before that (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you can approach this, leveraging the [JavaScript `max()` Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp)

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.services-area').map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}));

$('.services-area').height(max)
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dnd4ukgr/)

Comment: I agree on the first part, but the second part you can put in one line like ```$(".services-area").css("height", max + "px");```

Comment: @Thalsan hey nice suggestion, I overlooked targeting all `.services-area` at once. I ditched my `each` and can just call `height` directly

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".services-area").each(function () {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
}).height(maxHeight);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hswz7ed4/)**